# Maple fails for definite integral with integer parameters

Tags: integration, maple

In maple I compute the (very simple) definite integral of the product of two cosine functions:

```
restart;
f := n -> (x -> cos(n*x)):

assume(n1::integer);
assume(n2::integer);

int(f(n1)(x)*f(n2)(x),x=0..2*Pi);
```

It (unfortunately) returns

```
0
```

However it should be `Pi` for `n1=n2`.

Surprisingly

```
int(f(n1)(x)*f(n1)(x),x=0..2*Pi);
```

gives the correct result. Am I using maple the wrong way or is this a bug? If it's a bug, how can I avoid it? I am going to write a large program which will have to evaluate many terms which all reduce to integer-dependent integrals of this type.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to revise your expectation (or your assumptions) to cover another corner-case, since if `n1=n2=0` then the integral should equal `2*Pi`.

```
restart:

int(cos(0*x)*cos(0*x),x=0..2*Pi);
                          2 Pi

int(cos(3*x)*cos(-3*x),x=0..2*Pi);

                           Pi

int(cos(2*x)*cos(2*x),x=0..2*Pi);

                           Pi

ans1 := int(cos(n1*x)*cos(n2*x),x=0..2*Pi,AllSolutions)
       assuming n1::integer, n2::integer;

      piecewise(n1 - n2 = 0, Pi, 0) + piecewise(n1 + n2 = 0, Pi, 0)

simplify(ans1) assuming n1::integer, n2::integer, n1=n2, n1=0;

                          2 Pi

simplify(ans1) assuming n1::integer, n2::integer, n1=n2, n1<>0;

                           Pi

simplify(ans1) assuming n1::integer, n2::integer, n1<>n2, n1<>-n2;

                           0
```

You might also want to consider the integral under assumptions that `n1` and `n2` are both positive integers (which has a simpler conditional result, which might even be what you had in mind).

```
ans2 := int(cos(n1*x)*cos(n2*x),x=0..2*Pi,AllSolutions)
       assuming n1::posint, n2::posint;

             piecewise(n1 - n2 = 0, Pi, 0)

simplify(ans2) assuming n1=n2;

                           Pi

simplify(ans2) assuming n1<>n2;

                           0
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it seems to be a bug of my maple version (9.5), which in contrast to your version returns `ans1:=0`.